# Why AngularJS custom filter not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I'm using angular.min.js file (AngularJS v1.6.4)

And I'm trying to implement a simple filter that reverses a string.

Here is my code:

**main.js:**

```
var app = angular.module("angularBlackbox", []);

app.filter('reverse', function () {
   return function (item) {
       item.split("").reverse().join("");
   };
});

app.controller("MyController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
        message: ""
    };

    $scope.reversedMessage = function (message) {
        return message.split("").reverse().join("");
    }
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AngularJS Blackbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="angularBlackbox">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.message">
        <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ reversedMessage(data.message) }}</h1>
        <h2>{{ data.message | reverse }}</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get such result:

[image: result]

So we can see that:

1. data binding works [**OK**];
2. controller's function reversedMessage works [**OK**];
3. filter doesn't work [**Not OK**] (heading `<h2>{{ data.message | reverse }}</h2>` is not visible)

Why is the custom filter not working?

Comment: You dont `return` from your `filter` - `return item.split(...`

Comment: You're missing a return on your filter...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Return is missing. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` formatted output from your filter.

```
app.filter('reverse', function () {
   return function (item) {
       //returned reversed string from here.
       return item.split("").reverse().join("");
   };
});
```

[**Check Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/dWvsf9QELrZIdJ7ZG0xw?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

// You need to return the filtered data.

```
app.filter('reverse', function () {
   return function (item) {
       return item.split("").reverse().join("");
   };
});
```

Comment: Forgot to write Return statement. Yes. Thanks for your answer!